# jquery zoomer rebind after image source changed by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I made a small image gallery with one big image along with few small ones under neath. there is a zoomer attached with big image and when i click on small image it replaces the big image but zoomer shows the old image instead of new one

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //fire on DOM ready
            $('#myimage').addpowerzoom()
            })
```

javascript

```
function movImg(img){
    var bImg = document.getElementById('myimage');
    bImg.src=img.src;
$(document).trigger("ready");
}
```

html

```
<img id="myimage" src="img/abc.jpg"  alt="" />
<image src="thumbnails/xyz.jpg" onClick="movImg(this);" width="73px" style="cursor:  pointer;" />
```

where i am wrong or what's the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try to call `$('#myimage').addpowerzoom();` instead of `$(document).trigger("ready");`</strike>

This worked for me. It looks like the slight delay that happens when you change the source of the image breaks powerzoom. The idea is to call `addpowerzoom()` *after* image is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-AU">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ddpowerzoomer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function movImg(img){
                var bImg = document.getElementById('myimage');
                bImg.src = img.src;
                jQuery('#myimage').one("load", function() {
                    jQuery('#myimage').addpowerzoom();
                });
            };

            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#myimage').addpowerzoom();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="myimage" src="img/abc.jpg"  alt="" />
        <img id="thumb" src="thumbnails/xyz.jpg" onClick="movImg(this);" width="64px" style="cursor:  pointer;" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope its just a typo, but it should be `<img src="thumbnails/xyz.jpg"...` instead of `<image ...>`